# mootools conflicting with iepngfix.htc

Tags: mootools, mootools1.2, iepngfix

I have just placed iepngfix.htc to fix the PNG problem in ie 6, but when I include the mootools 1.3 png fix is not working.

Do you have any fixing code for this?

Thanks
Avi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only use one pngfix, because they both do the same thing.